# How to create online payment system by making own payment method?

Tags: payment-methods, payment, payment-gateway, magento2.1.5, credit-card

I have been trying to implementing a payment system in my store by creating own payment method.

I am trying to implement this through the use of API of payment gateway provided by a local bank. I got a very helpful and educational module named SamplePaymentGateway [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples/tree/master/sample-module-payment-gateway).

I installed it on my project. It created the admin configuration section. There is my own payment method option available at frontend checkout page as shown below.[image]

My question is how can I enter the card information for payment process?
Where will I do this?

jonijones suggested me to study the [official documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/payments-integrations/bk-payments-integrations.html). I understood almost everything pointed out there. But I could not find any document that gave clear concept of how we could show a form to enter credi card credentials.

I have followed the documentation thoroughly and made a working module but the feature is same as magento's out-of-box offline payment system.
It would be much help if you could guide me to show a form to submit credit card credentials in checkout page.

**Till now the payment system seems like offline system.**

Comment: maybe [this](https://github.com/jslingerland/BluePay_Payment_M2) will help you

Comment: Thank you for reference to this beautiful module. I'm checking it out. But I could not sign up on their site to get merchand id and passkey.

Comment: The mentioned module in the previous comment it's not a good example to implement own payment integration because it based on deprecated functionality. Please, look at http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/payments-integrations/bk-payments-integrations.html, it contains all necessary information.

Comment: @jonijones Thanks dude, investing time on this tutorial.